# Changing css with data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, data-binding

as you can see there is a MsgIsNew in select command with type of Bit in my sql data base. how can i put the BodyLiteral, in a span tag, if the valu of MsgIsNew field, is true?
I'm using asp.net with C#.
Thank you very much.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("MasSender") %>' Width="100%" Wrap="False">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="BodyLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MsgBody") %>'></asp:Literal>
            </td>
        </tr>            
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="DateLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# DisplayDate(Eval("MsgDate")) %>'></asp:Literal>
            </td>                
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>


SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT MsgIsNew, MsgBody, MsgDate, FROM Message"
```

Comment: You did not even say what kind of control is that. We need more information. In additions, please remove the unnecessary codes and format properly.

Comment: I edited the code and the question. is it clear now?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("MasSender") %>' Width="100%" Wrap="False">
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("MsgIsNew") %>'>
                <asp:Literal ID="BodyLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MsgBody") %>'></asp:Literal>
            </asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>            
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Literal ID="DateLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# DisplayDate(Eval("MsgDate")) %>'></asp:Literal>
        </td>                
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or maybe more exact:

Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("MsgIsNew")) %>

But you need to be sure that the return from database is boolean or by converting (0 or 1)...

If this is not what you ment please be more specific.